# How to debug styling supposedly being applied but not visible on the page?

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend, accessibility

I have been trying to apply some styling for a form input and am a bit stumped.

I have been attempting to apply the below styles to my form input and it is displayed in [Google Devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0W7l.png) as expected however no styling appears on the [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oblXa.png).

I have already tried:

1. applying the styling using a class or the id 'selectedFile' to increase the specificity.
2. applying the same styling to it using focus or just to display it normally and no styling appears but it always appears in devTools saying it is applied.
3. Adding a high z-index (not pretty but in theory would bring it to the front of the page if the styling is being applied behind other page elements) - no joy.
4. Removing the outline offset completely, setting it to a minus number (to display inside the box) and to a positive number (to display outside the box) and no joy with any.

Any ideas what I'm missing???

```css
input[type="file"]:focus-visible {
    z-index: 9999999 !important;
    outline-style: solid !important;
    outline-width: 4px !important;
    outline-color: blue !important;
    outline-offset: -4px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input pointer" id="selectedFile" (change)="fileChange($event)" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet">
      <label class="custom-file-label" for="selectedFile">{{selectedFileName | async}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **The code snippet works fine** if I use the **TAB** key to set focus on the FILE element. Using keyboard navigation is one of the ways in which `:focus-visible` is supposed to be activated, see https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus-visible/. Note that it will work better to use an actual color such as **`red`** in the code snippet (and not `$primary`).

Comment: Hi @PeterB,
Good point re. the colours sorry. I have changed that now. Frustratingly yeah it works in the code snippet but not in my actual code. I included links to screenshots of my devTools and the box unstyled to show you but I can't work it out.

Comment: What happens if you (1) click on the FILE element, (2) close the File Browse popup, (3) hit Tab followed by Shift-Tab (to shift focus away from and back to the element)?

Comment: @PeterB Following the instructions you provided there is focus styling applied which I believe is the browser default styling but nothing I have written. I also struggle to fins where that styling even comes from in the css.

Comment: Cheers for your help @PeterB ! I appreciated your time

Answer (score 0):

So apparently styling File Inputs is notoriously difficult and can be a bit fiddly at times.

As it happens I found a fix here:
https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/

All I needed to do was add a `+ label` to my styling now it works (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc1MD.png)).

```
input[type="file"]:focus-visible + label {
z-index: 9999999 !important;
outline-style: solid !important;
outline-width: 4px !important;
outline-color: blue !important;
outline-offset: 2px !important;}
```